# Фиксация таблицы в html

Tags: html

Мы имеем таблицу, которая располагается по центу нашей страницы. При сдвиге границ она двигается. Вопрос: Как её зафиксировать? ]

[image: Полноэкранный режим]

[image: Сдвиг поля в право]

```
<table id="node"  align="center">
    <caption><h1>Список ссылок</h1></caption>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>url</th>
        <th>status</th>
        <th>delete</th>
        <th>edit</th>
    </tr >
    <?php foreach($url_list as $val) : ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo  $val->id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo  $val->name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo  $val->url; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo  $val->status; ?></td>
    <td><button onClick="location.href='/welcome/delete/<?=$val->id?>';return false;">Delete‌​</button></td>
    <td><button>Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <tr>
        <td class=></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name1" size="10" maxlength="20"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="url1" size="10" maxlength="20"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="status1" size="10" maxlength="20"></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Add row"></th>

    </tr>

 </table>
```

Comment: Добавьте таблицу как запускаемый код `html`. Скриншот _может_ тогда и не пригодится, но даже если нужен, обрежьте его.

Comment: нужен код а не скриншот

Comment: Правил и добавил код

Comment: @J.Jones Уберите код php, оставьте только нужный `html`. Сделайте код запускаемым. И укажите что значит по центру? Вертикально, горизонтально? При сдвиге страницы куда?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам надо зафиксировать таблицу по центру, можно задать блоку с таблицей `margin:0 auto;` Если вам все же захочется вычислять какой-то хитрый марджин, то css уже давно умеет так (например): `margin-left: calc(50vw - 150px);` где 50vw - это половина ширины экрана, а 150px (или сколько там надо) - половина ширины таблицы.

Answer (score 3):

Укажите `margin-left` (или `margin-right`, в зависимости от того где зафиксировать таблицу слева или справа) в пискелях или просто отцентрируйте таблицу через `margin: 0 auto;`.

### UPDATE

Спасибо участнику @Mikl за вдохновение. Только можно не рассчитывать вручную ширину таблицы, а сделать это с помощью свойства `transform`. Тогда CSS для вашей таблицы будет выглядеть так:

```
table {
  margin-left: 50vw;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: @J.Jones Обновил ответ.